# Resolve PHPMailer Error SMTP Connect failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

How do I resolve this error in phpmailer? This never happened when I had tested this few months back.

```
2019-06-18 15:26:33 Connection: opening to ssl://localhost:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 

2019-06-18 15:26:33 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`server18.hostingraja.org' did not match expected CN=`localhost' 
2019-06-18 15:26:33 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto 
2019-06-18 15:26:33 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://localhost:465 (Unknown error) 
2019-06-18 15:26:33 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
2019-06-18 15:26:33 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`
```

Comment: You are attempting to connect locally (`localhost`) to an SMTP server on the same box.  *Is that what you intend?*  Can you validate the SMTP server is functionally working (separately) without this PHPMailer code being your only litmus test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is

> Peer certificate CN=`server18.hostingraja.org' did not match expected CN=`localhost'

So your code (which you didn't show) is probably doing something like:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Host = 'localhost`;
```

This can't work because you can't get a verifiable certificate for `localhost`. Two ways to fix this:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->Port = 25;
```

This simply disables encryption, which you don't need because you're only connecting to localhost.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Host = 'server18.hostingraja.org`;
```

This way you're still connecting to the same server, but using the correct name so that the certificate can be verified.

If you have any other issues, read the troubleshooting guide that the error message links to, and search before you post.